# Can not change the image of Imageview from another class

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview, layout-inflater

I have a MainActivity where most of my code is written. I have an imageview in my activity_main.xml which i am setting to a default image in Mainactivity.

My another file "OnSwipeTouchListener" is listening for swipe and double tap events, i have written the code to change the image of the imageview when the user double taps but my code does not work, nor it gives any error. (I am using Layoutinflater to inflate the activity_main file).

Here is the OnSwipeTouchListener

```js
package com.backspace.memebook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener extends MainActivity implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    public Context ctx;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("double tap");
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            ImageView isFunny = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.isFunny);
            isFunny.setImageResource(R.drawable.funny);
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Mainactivity does not have much code, it just sets a default image of the imageview which is showing fine but when i try to change it using another class, it doesn't change.

ANybody has got any clues?

Comment: You need to inflate and store the reference to the view in your MainActivity. Means: onCreate() stores the view which can be accessed from your GestureListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As writte in a comment, you need to inflate the view in your activity. Something like that should work (untested)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
public ImageView iv = null;
public void onCreate(....) {
    setContentView( ... ); 
    iv = findViewById(....);
}

public class OnSwipeTouchListener extends MainActivity implements OnTouchListener {
    //public ImageView iv from MainActivity
    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.funny); //iv is accessable, you may also use a constructor to pass the reference.
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to pass the reference to your ImageView inside the constructor of your GestureListener instead of accessing the data from OnSwipeTouchListener

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating again your layout inside a view that is not present inside your activity. You should use findViewById inside onCreate after setContentView and change ImageView background inside your onDoubleTap().

Comment: `use findViewById inside onCreate`. Can be done in onDoubleTab() as well.

Comment: @greenapps Yes but is not a best practice because if you use findViewById inside onCreate it will be done once , if you use findViewById inside onDoubleTap() it will be done every time user tap imageview.